# Disallow window creation in process

Tags: c#, process

I am creating a process to do some working. But the process is starting a black window (like the cmd). I have tried to set the CreateNoWindow = true but that doesn't help.

Is there another way to disallow window creation?

Here is my code:

```
var worker1 = new Process();

worker1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
worker1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
worker1.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
worker1.StartInfo.Arguments = job.BtcFilePath;
worker1.StartInfo.FileName = job.ExeFilePath;
worker1.Exited += new EventHandler(Worker1Exited);

Processors.Add(worker1);

Processors.Last().Start();
Processors.Last().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
```

*The Processors is a list of processors

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
worker1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
worker1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

This worked for me in a similar situation.

```
worker1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

This seems to be another option. (Did not test this, but found this while browsing http://www.dotnetperls.com/png)

Comment: Perfect :D Can you explain me what it does?

Comment: Description for UseShellExecute: `true if the shell should be used when starting the process; false if the process should be created directly from the executable file. The default is true.` - The shell manages all windows (I assume it does anyway,) so not using the shell will stop the window from being created.